# KendoUI Grid MVC Custom popup not working

Tags: kendo-ui, kendo-grid, kendo-asp.net-mvc

I want a toolbar item that open a kendo window with a custom action, without using any template...
I tried that:

```
...
.ToolBar(toolbar => toolbar.Create())
.Editable(editable => editable.Mode(GridEditMode.PopUp).Window(x => x.LoadContentFrom("MyAction", "MyController")))
...
```

Its not working... It always open a window with default Grid Model...

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must use an editor template in order to customize the popup editor window of the grid. You can check this sample project that shows how to do the same: http://www.kendoui.com/code-library/mvc/grid/custom-popup-editor.aspx